# shell script was not terminating

Tags: bash, shell

I am executing one shell script from another shell script. The included shell script is not terminating after execution. But when I run it separately, it works fine and terminates normally.

**Script 1**

```
#! /bin/bash

WebApp="R"

#----------Check for Web Application Status
localWebAppURL="http://localhost:8082/"
if curl --max-time 5 --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$localWebAppURL"; then
   WebApp="G"
else
   exec ./DownTimeCalc.sh &
fi

echo "WebApp Status|\"WebApp\":\"$WebApp\""
```

In above script I am calling another script called DownTimeCalc.sh.

**DownTimeCalc.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

WebApp="R"
max=15

for (( i=1; i <= $max; ++i ))
do
    if curl --max-time 5 --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "http://localhost:8082/"; then
        WebApp="G"
        echo "Status|\"WebApp\":\"$WebApp\""
        break
    else
        WebApp="R"
        sleep 10
    fi
    echo "Status|\"WebApp\":\"$WebApp\""
done
echo "finished"
exit
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you are actually seeing, which leads you to conclude that the second script is not terminating?

Comment: It's not coming back to normal terminal mode. It's just waiting after printing "finished".

Comment: after execution, terminal was not in interactive mode.

Comment: I think it was. Press Enter and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: yeah. After pressing enter it is coming to interactive mode. But How can I avoid that...?

Comment: You cannot. That is how `&` works. That is how `&` has always worked since I started using Linux in the 1990s.

Comment: then How can I overcome that problem..?  Is there  any alternate solution for that.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Maybe you need to use the `wait` command.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> exec ./DownTimeCalc.sh &
> ```

You don't need `exec`. If you want to run the script and wait for it to complete then just write:

```
./DownTimeCalc.sh
```

Or if you want to run it in the background and have the first script continue, write:

```
./DownTimeCalc.sh &
```

Comment: I want to run it in the background. I tried this one also "./DownTimeCalc.sh &". But still its not terminating.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `&` the launched process will be launched in the background and will run in the background while other commands from the foreground script run or you interact with the shell. It's doing what you told it. If you press Enter you will see any queued-up stderr output, and if you type `fg` it will bring the process to the foreground if it is still running.

You probably don't want to use `&` in this case, though.